# How do I interpret the results of the findCorrelation() function?

Tags: r, correlation, r-caret, feature-selection

I am having trouble with the findCorrelation() function, Here is my input and the output.

```
>findCorrelation(cor(subset(segdata, select=-c(56))),cutoff=0.9)
[1] 16 17 14 15 30 51 31 25 40
>cor(segdata)[c(16,17,14,15,30,51,31,25,40),c(16,17,14,15,30,51,31,25,40)]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFa0u.png)

I deleted the 56 colum because this is factor variable.

Above the code, I use cutoff=0.9. it means print only those variables whose correlation is greater than or equal to 0.9.
But, in the result image file, the end variable(P12002900) has very very low correlation. As i use "cutoff=0.9", Low correlations such as P12002900 should not be output. 
why this is printed??

so I use Vehicle bigdata that presented in R.

```
>library(mlbench)
>library(caret)
>data(Vehicle)
>findCorrelation(cor(subset(Vehicle,select=-c(Class))),cutoff=0.9)
[1]3 8 11 7 9 2
>cor(subset(Vehicle,select=-c(Class)))[c(3,8,11,7,9,2),c(3,8,11,7,9,2)]
```

this is result image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfWuU.png)

the last variable(Circ) has lower than 0.9 correlation.
but it is printed....

please help me... thanks you for your help!

Comment: @Chamoli / I can't share my data... it is protected by company... so I wrote Vehicle example. Do you know why low correlation was printed?

Comment: You are getting confused here. The indices that you get are of the variables that have high correlation with other variables remaining in the data set and not within them self. If you check out correlation of `Circ` with other variables in the the data frame you would see that it is highly correlated with `Max.L.Rect`. that is why only `Max.L.Rect` is kept and `Circ` removed.

Comment: @Chamoli / wow! Very thank you chamoli!! I thought there is high correlation between 3,8,11,7,9,2 colums  and 3,8,11,7,9,2 colums. Your opinion is that there is no correlation between 3,8,11,7,9,2. just 3,8,11,7,9,2colums have high correlation with other variables right? Thank you!!

Comment: Exactly. However the indices you got could be correlated too within themself but the main thing is that these indices are correlated with the variables in the data set and should be removed.

Comment: @Chamoli / very thank you. I am troubled for three days. but now I solve this because of you. Thank you.

Comment: @Chamoli /May I ask you one more question if you do not mind? 
I have asked the stack overflow question, but have not received a response for a long time. >library(mlbench) / library(rpart) / library(caret) /data(BreastCancer) / m<-rpart(Class~.,data=BreastCancer) / varImp(m) /
If you run the above code in order, you will get the results. But I do not know what overall means in the result. This function is related to variable selection like findCorrelation. Do you know?

Comment: You should use `?varImp`, anyways overall means overall importance while complementary would be relative which would give you the relative importance.

Comment: @Chamoli / Then, higher overall means more important value??  in ?varImp, there is no explanation.very thank you your kindness and sorry for inconveniencing to you.

Comment: Yes higher overall importance would mean a higher impact on the dependent variables.

Comment: @Chamoli / 
Thank you very much. I have raised this question and I have not received the answer for more than a week. Thank you very much for your kind and meticulous reply. Have a good night.

Comment: @Chamoli / Hi Chamoli..!!!

Comment: sorry for inconveniencing to you. I also posted a question on stackoverflow and looked for other ways, but I did not get an answer to the new question, so I found you. I would like to ask questions about multi-collinearity in relation to the vif index. Is it ok to ask?

Comment: It is fine. you should mail me your problem and i will get back to you.